# Select sprite by Touch better Method

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

From the begging of my objective c and cocos2d coding i have been using the sequential search method to select an sprite. Each time I detect a touch I search each object from my array list and then identify if the touch is on the sprite area if I gets the object then I select that sprite. 
This is the method Known by me.

the problem with the method is that if the object list become huge then it may take time and even when we are working with one array then it locks the array we con do nothing with that array.

Do anyone know better method except this one?

Comment: is this a real concern or are you afraid of being afraid? have you measured a performance issue, if yes on what device, after how many sprites in your array ?  No matter how you do this, there is bound to be an array somewhere that is searched (somehow) to determine if the touch affects an object. Show some code if you have a real issue.

Comment: The only other method is to register each sprite as a touch handler, and have each check themselves whether or not they have been touched, but this would probably not really help performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CCMenuItemImage` instead of `CCSprite`. You can choose a selector once the item is touched and of course can apply an image like a regular sprite with the following method :

```
itemFromNormalImage:selectedImage:target:selector:
```

You will also have to create a menu to contain this menu items, otherwise touching them won't work. Just create an instance of `CCMenu` and add the items to this menu then add the menu to your layer.

About effiency, well you will have to make some benchmarking with both implementations as this one is more convenient but not necessarily faster

Comment: its good. But when i am dealing with more than hundred object, in that case, will it be efficient? Using menuitem is good idea for selecting object and performing action. But as far as I know, I have to add menu for individual object and if I need to drag then what will happen? To drag we also have to keep it is a Array and the same thing will happen.

Comment: You can create one menu for all of your sprites and if you look in the source code you can see it handles touch events so you can try subclassing it (or change the source) to keep a reference (no array needed) on the touched item until touch end is detected

Answer (score 0):

Locks array? then just use one more pointer for object.

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mSpriteArray];

    for(CCSprite *sprite in array)
    {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], touchPoint))
        {
          //touched...
        }
    }
```